# How to use jQuery to reset two consecutive select lists after one click?

Tags: jquery, list, select, reset

The following is a shortened code for people to select hour, minute and day in a time slot. There are more than 1 time slot for people to select and enter date time values into.

I want to write a jQuery to reset two select lists to the first option at the same time (i.e. resetting both Hour and Min to option value="", also clearing information typed into the input box, by pressing the Delete button (with a X in a circle button) with the class .Del-btn.

Check out the following code:

```
 <div class="service_time_slot_input" id="timeslot2" style="display:none">
     <select name="adv_service_slot_hour2" class="Start_text_dropdown_box_mini">
         <option value="">Hour</option>
         <option value="00">00</option>
         <option value="01">01</option>
         <option value="22">22</option>
         <option value="23">23</option>
     </select>:
     <select name="adv_service_slot_min2" class="Start_text_dropdown_box_mini">
         <option value="">Min</option>
         <option value="00">00</option>
         <option value="05">05</option>
         <option value="50">50</option>
         <option value="55">55</option>
     </select>
     <input type="text" name="adv_service_slot_date2" class="datepicker advanced_service_shortbox" placeholder="Date2">
     <button type="button" id="delete2" class="Del-btn btn-danger">X</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" id="add_more2">Add</button>
 </div>
```

I wrote this jQuery code:

```
$('.Del-btn').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('input').val('');
    $(this).parent().find('select option:first').prop('selected',true);
});
```

This code works deletes the information in the input box (Date as a calendar), as well as the select option for the Hour select list, but the option in the Min select list is not reset.

The class Start_text_dropdown_box_mini was not used to reset both Hour and Min. It is  because the code is for one of the 10 time slots in the form. Each time slot has a delete button next to it. Each click resets the hour/min/date values in 1 time slot only. If the class Start_text_dropdown_box_mini is used, one click in 1 reset button will reset all the values in all of the 10 time slots.

How to add a new line of jQuery code to make it reset both the Hour and Min select lists with a click of the delete button?

Thanks!

Comment: $("#selectID").empty() would empty the list.

Comment: @maverickosama92: emptying the lists will not help here. He just wants to reselect the first list items and clear the input.

Comment: Odd you now prefer a slower more complex answer *made 30 mins later*, but that's your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following:

```
$('.Del-btn').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('input').val('');

  //Or
  //$('.Start_text_dropdown_box_mini').each(function(){
  //  $(this).children("option:first").prop("selected",true);
  //});

  $(this).parent().find('.Start_text_dropdown_box_mini').each(function(){
    $(this).children("option:first").prop("selected",true);
  });
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bMXdb/1/
i hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You were close to begin with. You can use val as well for Select lists (both your lists have a blank first value) Try this:

```
$('.Del-btn').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('input').val('');
    $(this).closest('.service_time_slot_input').children('select').val('');
});
```

It finds the closest parent div (class service_time_slot_input) then find the selects within that same div.

`parent` and `closest` do a similar job depending on how likely your structure is going to change I usually go with `closest` instead and target a specific parent. You can then use find for deeper searches. Examples of both styles are shown.

```
$('.Del-btn').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('input').val('');
    $(this).parent().find('select').val('');
});
```

JSFiddle to test http://jsfiddle.net/bRsZT/2/ has multiple controls that reset separately.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to give ids to first and second select list. Then using the id you can do so
$("#IDofSelectList option").eq(0).attr("selected", "selected")
hope it will help you out...

Comment: Actually you don't need ids as you can find the common parent and reset all the selects within that div. He was close using parent for the input.